# Nested query on Dynamodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, nodes

I am working on a project where i need to perform nested query over Dynamodb tables. Please let know if it is possible if yes then please provide a sample for `id not in(select id from table)` in node js

Answer (score 0):

Not supported. Select your id`s first and only then use it...